# Does the set of functions $\{\sin(2\pi x n\}_1^{\infty} \in BC([0,1],\Bbb R)$ separate points?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that $\{\sin(2\pi x n\}_1^{\infty} \in BC([0,1],\Bbb R)$ does or does not separate points.

I think that it does not. To show this, I want to find $a,b \in [0,1]$ such that if $a\neq b$ then $f(a) \neq f(b)$ where f is of the form above. I thought that choosing a=0 and b=1 would work, but it only does if n is a natural number. Thoughts about what else might work?

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\{\sin(2\,\pi\,n\,x)\}_1^\infty$ clearly suggests that $n$ is in fact a natural number.